Could an A220-300 swap engine types easily?
For example, could an A220-300 with the PW1521G swap engines to the PW1524G? If yes what obstacles need to be cleared for it to happen?

I think the answer to this question can be greatly improved if OP could say why he needs this information.

I have not been able to expressly confirm this for the PW1500G, but basically all modern FADEC-controlled engines within the same family are designed to be converted between thrust ratings with software changes only, and typically a 'thrust plug' hardware license key.
The PW1521G and 1524G are the same family designed to be fitted to the same aircraft, and therefore probably mechanically identical. Changing the engine type, therefore, wouldn't even require getting out a crane and changing the actual engine.
It's a matter of filing the appropriate paperwork, paying the fees to the engine manufacturer and possibly aircraft manufacturer, plugging in a new thrust plug, and changing settings. A higher thrust engine will degrade more quickly and require more frequent maintenance, and this will result in higher costs. Some airports might also charge higher fees, especially if the MTOW is also raised on paper.
This question has some information, mostly about the 737NG.

What is this "monica" stuff?

@Jpe61 Who or what is Monica and why so much notice from SE users?

Dang, I'm gonna need a more concice version to keep up interest...

As per EASA type certificate (link to pdf) all Pratt & Whitney PW1500G ensiges share a common "Engine Installation and Operating Manual" (PWA-8828).
It would therefore be safe to say that the engines share the same mechanical and electronic connections, and would be interchangeable as such.
The type certificate lists as the only difference between the PW1521G and the PW1524G models the "Data Storage Unit (Ratings Plug)". While not being a specialist in this matter I still would suggest the swap would not be entirely "plug and play", as there may be slight variance in control parameters such that some kind of adjustments might be necessary across the FADEC system.
The question mentiones that the engines on A220-300 are PW1521G. However this pdf document suggests that A220-300 (at the time of the creation of the document the CS300) uses PW1524G variant, and that the PW1521G is used in A220-100 (formerly CS100)
